# Fixing partitions and Installing BackTrack

Tags: windows, partitioning, multi-boot, backtrack

My whole problem started when I started trying to install Backtrack(3 or 4) Backtrack was trying to install itself over my entire windows partition (Which I had combined into one when I installed windows 7). So I booted back into windows 7 on my netbook (eee pc 1000 HE btw) I went into disk-manager with the aim of making a partition to install backtrack on but came out with a really screwed up drive. So I had two partions when I started: the windows system partition, and then my main partition and they were blue in diskmanager (I think that has something to do with formatting). After I went through the steps to  make a 10 GB FAT32 partition for backtrack I had about five partitons one called PE: that I have no Idea what it is the windows system file, my main partiton 10 GB unallocated space, and two other partions under 50MB each that are both unused space. And they were all converted to simple volumes (Green instead of blue). And backtrack still wants to erase my entire drive.

Question number 1: How do I get it back to the way it was?
Question 2: How to I get backtrack to dual boot on my netbook?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to create partitions inside Windows for backtrack, leave it as unallocated space, when going to install backtrack (I've used 4 though I found the partitioning can be a bit of a hassle) don't select "use entire disk" but there's 1 about using current partitions (probably just below) if not try using manual, and make partitions directly from here. 
Unfortunately the backtrack partition creator isn't that helpful, but if you fiddle around with it enough, you should be able to install backtrack without ruining your other partitions.